# paths in an $n\times n$ grid

Tags: combinatorics

Given an $n\times n$ square grid. Suppose only moving up or right is allowed. How many paths are there from the bottom-left corner to the top-right corner that don't cross the diagonal of the square that goes from the bottom-left corner to the top-right corner, expect at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics

Comment: @AnginaSeng But what about the paths that don't have any point in common with diagonal?

Comment: @LorenzoBenedetti: What about them? They’re included in that calculation.

Comment: @AnginaSeng But I'm only interested in those paths, not in all.

Comment: Read it further.  Understand it further.  Your answer will be expressible in terms of catalan numbers, whether you are interested in counting those paths who never cross the diagonal or whether you are interested in counting those paths who never intersect the diagonal.  To see the relation between those counts... rather than looking at the paths existing in the upper triangular region with corners $(0,0),(0,n),(n,n)$ who don't intersect the diagonal, look at the paths existing in the triangular region $(0,1),(0,n),(n-1,n)$ who never cross the diagonal.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, you're right, thank you

Comment: OP, I will have a closed form solution soon and add it to the answer.